# Should I give suggestion which is irrelevant to specific problem in answer?

Tags: discussion

When I was answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41071964/how-to-validate-no-duplicated-int-type-data-in-java/), I first give him some specific suggestions about his problem. I think, though, what he really need is to read a book rather than coding then asking on SO, so I leave the suggestion of

> Last, you should really get a book to read before trying to code.

But this suggestion was soon [edited out](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41071982/revisions).

So I wonder shouldn't I remind OP about that? Or should I change it to

> Last, you should really get a *BOOK NAME* to read before trying to code.

Comment: You can leave a constructive comment indicating they should learn about the basics before going to the trial and error phase but that's not part of the answer.

Comment: So, you mean I should leave a comment like 'you should really get a BOOK NAME to read before trying to code'?

Comment: *It seems you're missing a lot of the basics of Java. Reading a book, e.g. BOOK NAME will really improve your understanding.* - says the same thing, but in a polite way. [Be nice.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: @Glorfindel in comment?

Comment: Yeah, that's even better.

Comment: @Glorfindel OK, I understand it. Sorry about I didn't feel it.

Comment: That's no problem. I hope the user heeds your advice, that would be best for all of us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you leave it in a comment or at the *end* of an answer, it's ***how*** you say it that matters.

> Last, you should really get a book to read before trying to code.

Is a little rude.

Try:

To assist you with more java try reading "Book Name".

Comment: Personally if it's a resource that won't atrophy, e.g. a link, I'm in favour of adding it to the end of an answer.

Comment: ^^ an example of adding a comment after an answer ;)

Comment: If we should aim for questions and answers being canonical then the suggestion to the OP shouldn't be in the answer, unless you can say something like *above concepts are well explained in "book name"*. If not I would prefer leaving an comment.

Comment: @rene I don't think there is an issue with providing addition information. Many answers offer unasked suggestions to improve code. I'm a believer that going that extra mile is a good thing.